# Hilbert's approach to Riemann hypothesis using Fredholm's work:

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, ho.history-overview

I read somewhere that Hilbert wanted to prove Riemann hypothesis using Fredholm's work on integral equations but I can't find anything online.

Can someone provide historical references for it?

What's the present status of the approach?

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps the best documentation of that story, together with Polya's story of his similar response to a question from Landau, is at Andrew Odlyzko's page [https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/~odlyzko/polya/index.html](https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/%7Eodlyzko/polya/index.html)

In those days, prior to Stone's and vonNeumann's work on unbounded operators, their *resolvents* were much more tractable, proof-wise. So, Hilberts, Schmidt's, Fredholm's, Volterra's, and others' work on integral operators (often *compact*) were unassailably rigorous, in contrast to discussion of differential operators and other unbounded operators.

The general idea of finding/making self-adjoint operators whose eigenvalues are $s(s-1)$ for zeros $s$ of $\zeta$ (or similar...), has two general approaches. One is to make operators whose eigenvalues are parametrized in that way, and then show that they're self-adjoint. Alain Connes is a notable proponent of this approach.

The opposite approach (in which I've had some interest for a while) is to make "natural" self-adjoint operators (descended from Laplace-Beltrami operators on automorphic geometric objects) whose discrete spectrum... if any ... is related to zeros of zeta or other L-functions. This was pioneered in papers of Y. Colin de Verdiere in 1981-83. Since 2011, E. Bombieri and I have/had worked to be sure that various ideas supporting this could be made rigorous... and, sadly, showing that Montgomery's pair-correlation (and/or similar) showed that (unless RH is false!?!) not all the zeros of zeta can participate in the discrete spectrum of these operators. https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.07929  (Specifically, no more than $94\%$.)